# are there any low profile USB 3.0 flash drives?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, usb-3

I've searched for a USB 3.0 low-profile flash drive, and only found drives that are *either* USB 3.0 *or* low profile.  For instance, [Sandisk has only one USB 3.0 drive](http://www.sandisk.com/products/usb/drives/) at the time I'm writing this, and it is not low-profile.  Are flash drive manufacturers really that far behind?  I bought a USB 3.0 (spinning platter) hard drive about a year ago, and as far as I remember USB 3.0 had been around quite some time even then.

Can anyone point me to a low-profile USB 3.0 flash drive?

(And for extra credit can anyone explain why these people are so slow in releasing them?)

***UPDATE***: I'm asking if any drives like this ***EXIST*** -- not for product recommendations.  This is a legitimate question, not violating any of the guidelines of this site.

Comment: Shopping/Product recommendations are off-topic for SU.  As well, this question will become dated.

Comment: I'm not asking for a recommendation, I'm asking if such a product exists.  In two years it may become easier to find info on such products, but it won't become dated any more than any other question.   If I ask on stackoverflow about the "new" features of Ruby 1.9.3 it will become dated as well.  Everything will become dated.  Can you give a principled reason why this should be closed?

Comment: The FAQ says "If you have a question about…computer hardware…
and it is not about…a shopping or buying recommendation…then you’re in the right place to ask your question!".   Since (as pointed out in the previous comment) this is ***NOT*** asking for a buying recommendation, this question meets all those criteria, so it is clearly ***ON TOPIC*** according to the FAQ.  How many points do you get every time you close a question, whether it's on topic or off topic?

Comment: hehe We get no rep for closing. :)

Comment: [Here's a specific example of a question whose (top) answers are out of date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083451/debugging-in-ruby-1-9).  That in no way makes it a bad question.  That's just the way life is: [Πάντα ῥεῖ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_phrases).

Comment: I asked this specific question, is it technically feasible to have a low profile USB 3.0 device.  Too bad this was closed...

Comment: @chrish: IMHO some people get a bit over-zealous in their attempt to stamp out off-topic questions.